# Google chart add max value

Tags: javascript, css, graph, charts

I just want to change 20 to 21 because my max value 21 and i want to see it in my last line ..

```
vAxis: { 
viewWindowMode:'explicit',
viewWindow: {
    max:21,
    min:0
}
```

Here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ppfu5zsL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
vAxis: { 
ticks: [0,5,10,15,20,21],
viewWindowMode:'explicit',
viewWindow: {
    max:21,
    min:0
}
```